# Multi store shop on same domain in combination with ssl

Tags: magento-1.7, multistore

i want to setup a multi store magento.
Currently i have `www.domain1.com` and i want the new store to be on `www.domain1.com/outlet/`

This way i can use the same SSL certificate for both stores.

When i set this up in magento, and change the base url's i get a 404 error on `www.domain1.com/outlet/`

What am i missing?

I have magento 1.7.0.2 CE.

UPDATE 10-12-2013
This helped me a lot ... but i have got an extension the runs on www.domain1.com/facebookstore/ but www.domain1.com/outlet/facebookstore/ doesn't work ...

Am i missing something again?

Comment: Did you manage to resolve your issue?

Comment: Not yet, see my update

Comment: so this is just for that one extension?

Comment: already fixed it ...
I was forgotten to copy the right files to the theme!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 404 is caused because there is no url starting with `outlet` in Magento so it doesn't know the route. Basically you're telling Magento that the whole store is in a subdirectory.
In this case there are 3 options in my opinion

**Add storecode to URL**
The most basic option is to be found under `System > Configuration > Web` called the option `Add storecode to url`. In this case make sure your shops storecode is `outlet` and turn this option on. The drawback is however that this will also affect the existing stores adding the storecode to that one's urls as well

**Create a subdirectory**
You will need to create a subdirectory in your Magento installations root called `outlet` and copy the `index.php` in there. Also create symlinks for the `media`, `js` and `skins` directory and add an `.htaccess` (you can copy that one from the root)

**Work with subdomains**
Since a (most?) SSL certificate covers the whole TLD you can work with subdomains. In this case that would be `outlet.domain.com`. Just add this to you apache config and set the new storeviews base domain to that URL

Comment: Wouldn't outlet.domain.com only be covered with a wildcard ssl certificate? Most certificates I have seen mention only cover for www.domain.com or domain.com if not explicitly bought for another subdomain

Comment: You might be right, the certificates we use always cover all domains but then again I'm not the one that installs them :)

Comment: my ssl certificate only covers the main domain (and www.) not extra subdomains.